# slow hashing (sha256) on uboot 2009 (iMX25 processor)

Tags: hash, u-boot

Below calculation is done with uboot (2009 an older version) on iMX25 processor.
I am running sha256_process() function (sha256.c) under uboot to process 50Mbytes of data to get the hash.
It takes more than 100sec to complete the calculation. While the same hashing takes no time if run with openssl under Ubuntu (same processor).

Cross Compiler:
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc 4.4.1.

Need some input on what can possibly be the problem.

Tried another arm toolchain with improvement, but still not as expected.

---sha256 code.

```
static void sha256_process(sha256_context *ctx, const uint8_t data[64])
{
    uint32_t temp1, temp2;
    uint32_t W[64];
    uint32_t A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H;

    GET_UINT32_BE(W[0], data, 0);
    GET_UINT32_BE(W[1], data, 4);
    GET_UINT32_BE(W[2], data, 8);
    GET_UINT32_BE(W[3], data, 12);
    GET_UINT32_BE(W[4], data, 16);
    GET_UINT32_BE(W[5], data, 20);
    GET_UINT32_BE(W[6], data, 24);
    GET_UINT32_BE(W[7], data, 28);
    GET_UINT32_BE(W[8], data, 32);
    GET_UINT32_BE(W[9], data, 36);
    GET_UINT32_BE(W[10], data, 40);
    GET_UINT32_BE(W[11], data, 44);
    GET_UINT32_BE(W[12], data, 48);
    GET_UINT32_BE(W[13], data, 52);
    GET_UINT32_BE(W[14], data, 56);
    GET_UINT32_BE(W[15], data, 60);

#define SHR(x,n) ((x & 0xFFFFFFFF) >> n)
#define ROTR(x,n) (SHR(x,n) | (x << (32 - n)))

#define S0(x) (ROTR(x, 7) ^ ROTR(x,18) ^ SHR(x, 3))
#define S1(x) (ROTR(x,17) ^ ROTR(x,19) ^ SHR(x,10))

#define S2(x) (ROTR(x, 2) ^ ROTR(x,13) ^ ROTR(x,22))
#define S3(x) (ROTR(x, 6) ^ ROTR(x,11) ^ ROTR(x,25))

#define F0(x,y,z) ((x & y) | (z & (x | y)))
#define F1(x,y,z) (z ^ (x & (y ^ z)))

#define R(t)                    \
(                       \
    W[t] = S1(W[t - 2]) + W[t - 7] +    \
        S0(W[t - 15]) + W[t - 16]   \
)

#define P(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,x,K) {        \
    temp1 = h + S3(e) + F1(e,f,g) + K + x;  \
    temp2 = S2(a) + F0(a,b,c);      \
    d += temp1; h = temp1 + temp2;      \
}

    A = ctx->state[0];
    B = ctx->state[1];
    C = ctx->state[2];
    D = ctx->state[3];
    E = ctx->state[4];
    F = ctx->state[5];
    G = ctx->state[6];
    H = ctx->state[7];

    P(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, W[0], 0x428A2F98);
    P(H, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, W[1], 0x71374491);
    P(G, H, A, B, C, D, E, F, W[2], 0xB5C0FBCF);
    P(F, G, H, A, B, C, D, E, W[3], 0xE9B5DBA5);
    P(E, F, G, H, A, B, C, D, W[4], 0x3956C25B);
    P(D, E, F, G, H, A, B, C, W[5], 0x59F111F1);
    P(C, D, E, F, G, H, A, B, W[6], 0x923F82A4);
    P(B, C, D, E, F, G, H, A, W[7], 0xAB1C5ED5);
    P(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, W[8], 0xD807AA98);
    P(H, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, W[9], 0x12835B01);
    P(G, H, A, B, C, D, E, F, W[10], 0x243185BE);
    P(F, G, H, A, B, C, D, E, W[11], 0x550C7DC3);
    P(E, F, G, H, A, B, C, D, W[12], 0x72BE5D74);
    P(D, E, F, G, H, A, B, C, W[13], 0x80DEB1FE);
    P(C, D, E, F, G, H, A, B, W[14], 0x9BDC06A7);
    P(B, C, D, E, F, G, H, A, W[15], 0xC19BF174);
    P(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, R(16), 0xE49B69C1);
    P(H, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, R(17), 0xEFBE4786);
    P(G, H, A, B, C, D, E, F, R(18), 0x0FC19DC6);
    P(F, G, H, A, B, C, D, E, R(19), 0x240CA1CC);
    P(E, F, G, H, A, B, C, D, R(20), 0x2DE92C6F);
    P(D, E, F, G, H, A, B, C, R(21), 0x4A7484AA);
    P(C, D, E, F, G, H, A, B, R(22), 0x5CB0A9DC);
    P(B, C, D, E, F, G, H, A, R(23), 0x76F988DA);
    P(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, R(24), 0x983E5152);
    P(H, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, R(25), 0xA831C66D);
    P(G, H, A, B, C, D, E, F, R(26), 0xB00327C8);
    P(F, G, H, A, B, C, D, E, R(27), 0xBF597FC7);
    P(E, F, G, H, A, B, C, D, R(28), 0xC6E00BF3);
    P(D, E, F, G, H, A, B, C, R(29), 0xD5A79147);
    P(C, D, E, F, G, H, A, B, R(30), 0x06CA6351);
    P(B, C, D, E, F, G, H, A, R(31), 0x14292967);
    P(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, R(32), 0x27B70A85);
    P(H, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, R(33), 0x2E1B2138);
    P(G, H, A, B, C, D, E, F, R(34), 0x4D2C6DFC);
    P(F, G, H, A, B, C, D, E, R(35), 0x53380D13);
    P(E, F, G, H, A, B, C, D, R(36), 0x650A7354);
    P(D, E, F, G, H, A, B, C, R(37), 0x766A0ABB);
    P(C, D, E, F, G, H, A, B, R(38), 0x81C2C92E);
    P(B, C, D, E, F, G, H, A, R(39), 0x92722C85);
    P(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, R(40), 0xA2BFE8A1);
    P(H, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, R(41), 0xA81A664B);
    P(G, H, A, B, C, D, E, F, R(42), 0xC24B8B70);
    P(F, G, H, A, B, C, D, E, R(43), 0xC76C51A3);
    P(E, F, G, H, A, B, C, D, R(44), 0xD192E819);
    P(D, E, F, G, H, A, B, C, R(45), 0xD6990624);
    P(C, D, E, F, G, H, A, B, R(46), 0xF40E3585);
    P(B, C, D, E, F, G, H, A, R(47), 0x106AA070);
    P(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, R(48), 0x19A4C116);
    P(H, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, R(49), 0x1E376C08);
    P(G, H, A, B, C, D, E, F, R(50), 0x2748774C);
    P(F, G, H, A, B, C, D, E, R(51), 0x34B0BCB5);
    P(E, F, G, H, A, B, C, D, R(52), 0x391C0CB3);
    P(D, E, F, G, H, A, B, C, R(53), 0x4ED8AA4A);
    P(C, D, E, F, G, H, A, B, R(54), 0x5B9CCA4F);
    P(B, C, D, E, F, G, H, A, R(55), 0x682E6FF3);
    P(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, R(56), 0x748F82EE);
    P(H, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, R(57), 0x78A5636F);
    P(G, H, A, B, C, D, E, F, R(58), 0x84C87814);
    P(F, G, H, A, B, C, D, E, R(59), 0x8CC70208);
    P(E, F, G, H, A, B, C, D, R(60), 0x90BEFFFA);
    P(D, E, F, G, H, A, B, C, R(61), 0xA4506CEB);
    P(C, D, E, F, G, H, A, B, R(62), 0xBEF9A3F7);
    P(B, C, D, E, F, G, H, A, R(63), 0xC67178F2);

    ctx->state[0] += A;
    ctx->state[1] += B;
    ctx->state[2] += C;
    ctx->state[3] += D;
    ctx->state[4] += E;
    ctx->state[5] += F;
    ctx->state[6] += G;
    ctx->state[7] += H;
}
```

Expect the hashing time to be withing a few seconds, not 100sec.

Comment: Are the instruction/data caches of the i.mx25/ARM926EJ-S enabled at the time you are computing the hash ? They for sure are when computing the hash on Linux but they may not be in your current u-boot environment.

Comment: The numbers you provided could be consistent with one of both of the  instruction/data caches being off: using the `hash sha256  0x00080000 0x3200000` command on a u-boot 2019.10 + BCM2835  at 700Mhz (ARM11/ARM1176JZF-S), I got the following numbers:
dcache on, icache on: 3 seconds;
dcache off, icache off: 30 seconds

This could well have taken 100 seconds if my CPU frequency would had been 210 MHZ instead of 700 MHZ. By the way, what is the frequency your i.mx25 is running at ?

Comment: I forgot to mention the u-boot used for testing was compiled using armv5l-linux-musleabihf-gcc  8.3.0.

Comment: Thanks Frant, my i.mx25 is running at 400Mhz.Good input, let me check how to enable the cache and test further.

Comment: May I know how to disable / enable cache in uboot?

Comment: If your u-boot does not already include the `icache`/`dcache` commands, you may have to re-compile it after having added the following line to the configuration file: `CONFIG_CMD_CACHE=y`. Another option would be to enable it in your code programmatically prior to start computing the hash.

Comment: See section *4.3. Enabling the caches* and *2.3.2. Control Register c1* of the [ARM926EJ-S™ Technical Reference Manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0198e/Cacddigd.html). You would have to use for example `MRC p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 0` / `MCR p15, 0, r0, c1, c0, 0` in order to read/write Control Register C1 into/from general purpose register `r0`. You may want to read it from your code and display a message in  order to indicate whether or not the caches are enabled before investigating further.

Comment: Thanks again. I can confirm that dcache was not enabled for hash_calculate(). Then I enable it with dcache_enable() in uboot just before the hash calculation, unfortunately, no difference observed on the time took to complete the hash.

Comment: Does that mean the instruction cache was enabled already, i.e. icache_enable() had been called at one point in your u-boot prior to the computation ?

Comment: @ Frank Zheng: By the way, you should probably execute the exact same code on Linux in order to  make meaningfull comparisons: openssl does support the use of optimized code written in assembly for computing hashes - see file `sha256-armv4.pl`  in directory `crypto/sha/asm`. This may explain the differences you observed if you were comparing the performances of your code against openssl.

Comment: Hi Frant, not linux, I did run the same code on the later version of uboot (e.g. U-boot v2013), which works well without much delay. and I also start to compare the uboot configuration, cache is still the major concern. btw, both icache and dcache are enabled before my hash calculation. Maybe migrate the uboot to later version can be another option.

Comment: Hi Frant, I have fixed the issue. You are definitely on the right track. The only missing item is to setup MMU before enabling dcache. Thanks again.

Comment: Hello Frank, in the case my comments/suggestions would have helped, please feel free to accept the answer I just added upon reading your last comment - My current goal is to reach a reputation level of 1500 so that I may create new topics. By the way, I am very glad you solved your issue. Could you please elaborate on why enabling the MMU was required for the data cache to be enabled ? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in performance you did notice may be caused by one of both of the CPU Instructions/Data caches being disabled.

You can enable/disable both caches from u-boot provided that it was compiled with the `icache`/`dcache` commands.

If your u-boot does not already include the `icache`/`dcache` commands, you may have to re-compile it after having added the following line to the configuration file: `CONFIG_CMD_CACHE=y`.

Another option would be to enable it in your code programmatically prior to start computing the hash.